# JavaScript: initialize different image if an error occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a folder with the contents like the following (giving a minimal example)

```
ex1_1.png
ex1_2.png
ex2_1.png
page.html
```

and I've written the following JavaScript code.  The HTML file has two canvas elements that are designed to draw `ex1_1.png` and `ex2_1.png` and each canvas element has an associated "Next" button.  If the first one is clicked it erases the first canvas element and draws `ex_2.png`.  What I want is for the Next button to cycle through all my images, going back to the start when the last image is exceeded.  The following JavaScript accomplishes this, except for the part where it cycles back.  When it reaches the image with source `ex1_3.png` (which doesn't exist in the folder), I get a crash, but on the `draw()` command--which tells me that for whatever reason, it's not cycling the source back to `ex1_1.png` before attempting to draw.

To the best of my ability to debug this, something is going wrong with the `img.onerror` part, or how its implemented with the global variable `window.indicator`.  When I cycle through using the next button, the indicator shows `true` then `false` if I print the value from within the `img.onerror` function.  But if I print from within the `next()` function, it never shows `false`.  This sounds like some kind of an issue with the `window.indicator` keeping its value globally.

```
// Variable to indicate whether the most recently generated image
// was valid.
window.indicator = true;

// Give the file base-name and index as stored in the local address.
// Return the corresponding Image() object.
function initImg(name, ind) {
    var img = new Image();
    // The file is local, the image is always of the form
    // baseName_i.png
    window.indicator = true;
    img.src = name + "_" + ind + ".png";
    img.onerror = function() {
        // Find the appropriate canvas state element, and 
        // update its state back to 1.
        for (i = 0; i < canStates.length; i++) {
            var n = canStates[i][0].getAttribute("id");
            n = n.split("_")[1];
            if (name == canStates[i][0].getAttribute("id")) {
                canStates[i][1] = 1;
            }

            window.indicator = false;
        }
    };
    return img;
}

// Give the canvas context and image objects.  Draw the image to
// the context, no return value.
function draw(ctx, img) {
    // Check that the image is loaded before writing.  Keep
    // checking every 50 milliseconds.
    if (!img.complete) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            draw(ctx, img);
        }, 50);
    }

    // Clear the current image and draw the new.
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, 200,200);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, 200,200);
}

// Give the string canvas id and string base-name, create the
// canvas object and draw the first image to the canvas.
function slideShow(canId, name) {
    var can = document.getElementById(canId);
    can.width = 300;
    can.height = 300;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    var img = initImg(name, 1);
    draw(ctx, img);
}

// Next button function.  Give the name of the canvas, draw the
// next image or cycle to the start.
function next(button) {
    var name = button.getAttribute("name");
    // Find the appropriate canvas element.
    for (i = 0; i < canStates.length; i++) {
        var id = canStates[i][0].getAttribute("id");
        id = id.split("_")[1];
        if (id == name) {
            // Use the states to produce an image, and update the
            // states.
            canStates[i][1] += 1;
            var img = initImg(name, canStates[i][1]);
            if (!window.indicator) {
                img = initImg(name, 1);
            }
            // Draw to the canvas.
            draw(canStates[i][0].getContext('2d'),img);
        }
    }


}

// Create a global variable tracking all states of "Next" buttons.
// Stored as a list, each element is a list, the left coordinate is
// a canvas and the right coordinate is its state (image index).
// Also initialize all slide shows.
// The variable r stores the canvases and states, initialized
// outside the function in order to pass-by-reference so as to act
// as a global variable.
var canStates = new Array();
window.onload = function() {
    var cans = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");

    for (i=0; i < cans.length; i++) {
        var c = cans[i];
        var n = c.getAttribute("id").split("_")[1];
        slideShow("can_"+n, n);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cans.length; i++) {
        canStates[i] = [cans[i],1];
    }
}
```

I could switch strategies completely here.  I've heard that PHP is a decent way to server-side look at the files in a directory, and I could use that, but I don't know how to make a PHP script execute when a browser is loaded, or how to take its results and hand them over to the JavaScript file.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `img.onerror` method is getting fired when the image doesn't exist?

Comment: @VivekPradhan Yes, it seems to.  I inserted a `console.log(0)` command inside the `img.onerror` function and it prints 0 at the button click when it loads an image that doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you print `window.indicator` outside the `for` loop in `img.onerror` part. Also, do you think that `for` loop is needed? Also, I think you can remove the global dependency on `window.indicator` by returning an object that has both the `img` and `indicator` wrapped together in an object. Something like: `{img_src: img, valid: true/false}` can be returned in the `initImg` method

Comment: @VivekPradhan I moved the console log line outside the loop and it still works.  The for loop seemed necessary to find the part of `canStates` that I needed to set back to 1.  I could wrap the `img` and indicator into a single variable but what would that gain me?  Is this the solution?